# Given the following, is there equivalence relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations, congruences

Let $n$ be an integer. On the set $F$ of all integer-valued functions of a set $A$, suppose we define $f$ and $g$ to be related if $f(a)\equiv g(a)\pmod{n}$ for every $a\in A$. Is this an equivalence relation on $F$? Prove that it is, or explain why it isn’t.

I think maybe the integer-valued function is screwing me up. I get what it means; you put a value into a function and get an integer back (ceiling and floor are good examples), but I don't see how it affects the problem. I know I have to prove that it's reflexive, symmetric and transitive (or explain why it isn't), but I can't even figure out a starting point.

Comment: The starting point is to write down exactly what it would mean for this relation to be reflexive.

Comment: It would be reflexive if $f(a)\equiv f(a)\pmod{n}$, I think. Part of my problem is that F seems to be a set of functions...

Comment: Yes, $F$ is a set of functions, and you have defined a relation on this set of functions, and you're asked whether it's an equivalence relation on this set of functions. The relation is reflexive if **for every** $f$ **and every** $a$, $f(a)\equiv f(a)\bmod n$. So, is it reflexive? Then, what exactly does it mean for the relation to be symmetric? What exactly does it mean for the relation to be transitive? Don't leave out the quantifiers!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that would mean it is reflexive. I guess that would make it symmetric and transitive as well? Because the mod function is both symmetric and transitive.

Comment: No, that's not what "symmetric" means. Write out, carefully, what it would mean for the relation to be symmetric.

Comment: I think you might've seen it before I edited it, can you confirm (or deny)?

Symmetric would mean for every f and g where $f(a)\equiv g(a)\pmod{n}$, then $g(a)\equiv f(a)\pmod{n}$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I saw it before your edit. The "mod function" is not a function, and the words "symmetric" and "transitive" don't apply to functions. I still think it's best if you write out exactly what "symmetric" and "transitive" mean in the context of this problem. I think you may be ready to post an answer.

Comment: Sorry, would it be more correct to say mod relationship? Or mod congruence? I guess I was originally having trouble because I thought I was trying to deduce whether f and g would be congruent, knowing nothing else but that they're integer-valued functions. But that's not what's being asked. I have symmetric written above in the edited comment. Transitive would be: for every f, g and k, and $a\in A$, where $f(a)\equiv g(a)\pmod{n}$, and $g(a)\equiv k(a)\pmod{n}$, then $f(a)\equiv k(a)\pmod{n}$.

Comment: You're almost there. You've left out the "for all $a$" in a few places, and also a "for all $d$".

Comment: Do you mean for all k, instead of d? And thank you, this has been very helpful. I updated the previous comment to include the for all a.

Comment: It was $d$ when I read it. $f$, $g$, and $k$ are in $F$, not $A$. Anyway, why not post an answer to your question now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is an equivalence relation on F.

The relation is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.

Reflexive: for every $f\in F$ and $a\in A$, $f(a)\equiv f(a)\pmod{n}$. This is true.

Symmetric: for every $f, g\in F$ and $a\in A$, if $f(a)\equiv g(a)\pmod{n}$, then $g(a)\equiv f(a)\pmod{n}$. This is true.

Transitive: for every $f, g, k \in F$, and $a\in A$, where $f(a)\equiv g(a)\pmod{n}$ and $g(a)\equiv k(a)\pmod{n}$, then $f(a)\equiv k(a)\pmod{n}$. This is true.